# URL redirect is not working

Tags: php, popup, internet-explorer-11

Following example URL only seem to work for some users and not the others:  https://abc.123.com/123%20JS.html?ipaddr=123asp.abc.com&env=prod&app=abcupld.php

Users for whom the URL doesn't work see "Loading Please Wait..." message.

However, users for whom the URL is working get redirected to the following example URL:  https://abc.123.com/abcupldp/abcupld.php

What could be causing this issue? I compared IE settings between two computers, but everything seems to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a caching issue.  Clearing cache enabled the redirect.